# Search everything (posts, pages, tags, cpt, meta)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, functions, search, post-meta

I would like to know how to use the built in wordpress search to return results from all content on my site. Specifically, I want to search;

- posts
- pages
- tags
- custom post type (portfolio)
- custom taxonomy used in custom post type (skill, client)
- metaboxes used in custom post type (portfolio_caption, portfolio_excerpt, portfolio_credits, portfolio_links)

I would like one search form and don't need to limit the search to certain post types or categories. Just enter the search term > click search > see matches from all content on my site. Simple ;)

Update: Preferably, I would achieve this through a function or custom database query rather than using a plugin. This is because I'm developing a theme and want this functionality included out of the box rather than requiring a user to download a plugin. (title changed)

Comment: What is the fascination with "*without a Plugin*"? Downvote for this restriction, since it is essentially impossible to extend WordPress functionality without using the Plugin API.

Comment: Apologies for not explaining myself better. Rather than saying without a plugin, I should have said, that I'd like to achieve this through a function or custom database query. The "fascination" of not using a plugin is simply that I'm developing a theme and want to include this functionality out of the box without the need for a user to download a plugin. Thanks for taking a look at my question though.

Comment: There are ways to include plugins with theme installation, for example, https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Plugin-Activation

Comment: More importantly: anything you can do with a plugin, you can do out of functions.php...so it's really 6 of one or half a dozen of another.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I feel this question has become a plugin vs no plugin debate. That's my fault for making the original stipulation, sorry. Does anyone have any insight into how I can actually achieve the search outlined in the question? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DeluxeBlogTips.com](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/04/search-all-custom-fields.html) <sup>1)</sup> has an article on how to do combined searches in both posts and meta data. Basically, it involves two queries via the $wpdb object; one to search the meta table to get a list of `post_id`s and the other is a query of posts to get `post_id`s.  You then merge the arrays and use that to do a query with a `WP_Query` using the `posts__in` argument.

Using tags may be a bit tricky because 1. tags are meant to group posts together and 2. tags and taxonomies involve 3 different tables.

<sup>1) The linked article is not completely right. It should be `$keyword = "%".like_escape( $keyword )."%";`.</sup>

Comment: +1, but an additional note: Every time you try to involve taxonomy taxons (or even their meta), you are adding one additional (and slow) `JOIN` to the SQL query. This can be _very_ time consuming.

Comment: Didn't know about `like_escape`.  I'll need to remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the link @Wyck posted, check out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/. Given the complexity of the task, a plugin really is your best bet to get 'er done.

Comment: I tried Search Everything, and it did not find search content written into a Wordpress page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly opposed to a plugin, and know some SQL, you can do this with the [$wpdb global variable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

For example, to query all posts that contain "sample_text" in the title, you would do something like:

```
global $wpdb;    
$post = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%sample_text%' ");
```

Then you would do similar things for each of the other tables.

Comment: Always use `prepare()`, never use a fixed table prefix.

Comment: `LIKE` queries need to use [`like_escape()`](http://queryposts.com/function/like_escape/).